# Angular 2+ forumBuilder empty fields

Tags: angular

I have created a form by formBuilder, where I have select, options and inputs. When I get form to variable and print it to console I get:

```
{town: null, subject: ƒ, level: ƒ, priceMin: ƒ, priceMax: ƒ}
\/
level: ƒ String()
priceMax: ƒ Number()
priceMin: ƒ Number()
subject: ƒ String()
town: null
```

I need to create a custom form in function and pass it to another function, but what values to set to it when I want to treat variables field as empty? What values should I put in form in levels, priceMin, priceMax fields?

my function in component.ts

```
let form = {
    "town": null,
    "subject" : lesson, 
    "levels": null,
    "priceMin": null,
    "priceMax": null
};      

searchParametrsComponent.onSearchSubmit(form, this.privateLessons);
```

my form html code:

```
  <form 
    class="primary-data form-group"
    [formGroup]="searchForm"
    (ngSubmit)="onSearchSubmit(searchForm.value)"
  >
    <h4 class="primary-data__title">Filtry</h4>
    <div class="primary-data__subject">
    </div>
    <div class="primary-data__city">
       <div class="city">
        <label class="city__label" for="city">Miejscowość:</label>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          class="form-control" 
          id="town"
          formControlName="town"
        >
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="primary-data__subject">
      <div class="subject">
        <label class="subject__label">Przedmiot:</label>
        <div class="form-group select select--subject">
          <select  
            class="form-control"
            #selectedItem
            required
            formControlName="subject"
          >
            <option value="" [ngValue]="null" disabled selected>Kategoria</option>
            <option 
              class="subject-option"
              *ngFor="let subject of lessonSubjects"
            >
              {{ subject }}
            </option>

          </select>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="primary-data__range">
      <div class="range">
        <label class="range__label">Zakres Materiału:</label>
        <div class="form-group select select--range">
          <select  
            class="form-control"
            #selectedItem
            required
            formControlName="level"
          >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Poziom</option>
            <option class="range-option">Szkoła podstawowa</option>
            <option class="range-option">Gimnazjum</option>
            <option class="range-option">Liceum</option>
            <option class="range-option">Studia</option>
          </select>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="primary-data__price">
      <div class="price">
        <div class="price__title">Cena:</div>

        <label for="city">od:</label>
        <input 
          type="number" 
          class="form-control price__input" 
          id="from"
          formControlName="priceMin"
        >

        <label for="city">do:</label>
        <input 
          type="number" 
          class="form-control price__input" 
          id="from"
          formControlName="priceMax"
        >

      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary-data__button" value="SZUKAJ">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [W]hat values to set to it when I want to treat variables field as empty?

You choose what it means when a field is empty. Common choices are `''` (empty string), `null` and `undefined` for text fields, but it greatly depends on how the control value accessor has been implemented in order for something to visually be "empty".

> What values should I put in form in levels, priceMin, priceMax fields?

See above.